# Fontspec - Italic small caps with semi-bold

Tags: fonts, fontspec, italic, small-caps

I have problems when I use small italic capitals  with a "non-standard" font weight (here semi-bold).

I tried several things like `FontFace={sb}{it}{Font=LinLibertine_RZI_G. ttf, SmallCapsFont={LinLibertine_RZI_G. ttf}, SmallCapsFeatures={RawFeature={+smcp}}}}`, but it doesn’t work. I don’t know how to ask `Fontspec` to use the small semi-bold italic capitals.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}[
    FontFace = {sb}{n}{LinLibertine_RZ_G.ttf} ,
    FontFace = {sb}{it}{LinLibertine_RZI_G.ttf},
]

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}{\mathbf}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}

Hello world. \textsb{Hello world.} \textbf{Hello world.}

\textit{Hello world.} \textit{\textsb{Hello world.}} \textit{\textbf{Hello world.}}

\textsc{Hello world.} \textsb{\textsc{Hello world.}} \textbf{\textsc{Hello world.}}

\textit{\textsc{Hello world.}} \textit{\textsb{\textsc{Hello world.}}} \textit{\textbf{\textsc{Hello world.}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

After Egreg’s answer, here’s my new MWE, But the problem remains :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}[
    BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB_G.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI_G.ttf,
    FontFace={sb}{n}{LinLibertine_RZ_G.ttf},
    FontFace={sb}{it}{LinLibertine_RZI_G.ttf},
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}
\textit{\textsc{Hello world.}} \textit{\textsb{\textsc{Hello world.}}} \textit{\textbf{\textsc{Hello world.}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. E.g., are you looking to use semibold rather than (outright) bold as the default font weight for "bold", or do you wish to employ *both* semibold and bold? Please advise.

Comment: Did you try with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}`?

Comment: Hello @Mico, indeed, I use in my document the bold and semi-bold, so I wish I could use the small italic capitals in bold and semi-bold.

Comment: Hello @egreg, I just tried but it doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: @Bastien Yes, it does, but you also need to declare the bold font.

Comment: I don't have the Linux Libertine G fonts. If they're at all similar to the Linux Libertine O fonts, you may need to re-think the wisdom of using both the semibold and the bold font weights in one and the same document, as the two font weights are sufficiently similar as to make it difficult (or even impossible) for most readers to be able to tell whether a given word is rendered in semibold or bold.

Comment: The problem is that `LinLibertine_RZI_G.ttf` does not have small caps. You can check this with `otfinfo -f`.

Comment: That’s the Graphite version of the font. Linux Libertine O, the OpenType version, does support semibold italic small caps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why shouldn't old font commands such as `\rm` or `\it` or `\bf` used? Because they follow the original LaTeX setup and reset *all* font features. So if you do `\it\bf` you just get boldface and not italic.

The command `\DeclareOldFontCommand` should only be used for compatibility with older documents. If you look in the LaTeX kernel, you'll see that `\bfseries` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

You have also to declare what bold font you plan to use, if you define semibold.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
  BoldFont=* Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=* Bold Italic,
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{* Semibold},
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{* Semibold Italic},
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}

Hello world. \textsb{Hello world.} \textbf{Hello world.}

\textit{Hello world.} \textit{\textsb{Hello world.}} \textit{\textbf{Hello world.}}

\textsc{Hello world.} \textsb{\textsc{Hello world.}} \textbf{\textsc{Hello world.}}

\textit{\textsc{Hello world.}}
\textit{\textsb{\textsc{Hello world.}}}
\textit{\textbf{\textsc{Hello world.}}}

\end{document}
```

The fonts have been changed to suit my machine.

[image]

If I replace all periods with `.\typeout{\fontname\font}`, the terminal shows

```
"Linux Libertine O/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Semibold/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Bold/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Semibold Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Bold Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Semibold/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Bold/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Semibold Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"Linux Libertine O Bold Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
```

which seems to be what you're looking for.

Here's the setup for Libertinus Serif.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{*-Semibold},
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{*-SemiboldItalic},
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}

Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.
\textsb{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}
\textbf{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}

\textit{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}
\textit{\textsb{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}
\textit{\textbf{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}

\textsc{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}
\textsb{\textsc{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}
\textbf{\textsc{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}

\textit{\textsc{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}
\textit{\textsb{\textsc{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}}
\textit{\textbf{\textsc{Hello world\typeout{\fontname\font}.}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to check what fonts are being used, I added `\typeout{\fontname\font}` and on the terminal I get

```
"[LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Semibold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Italic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-SemiboldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Semibold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-Italic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-SemiboldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
"[LibertinusSerif-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
```

After seeing the output, both in the Linux Libertine and Libertinus serif cases, I believe that using both bold and semibold does not work, because the weights are not distinguishable enough: only if they're next to each other one can spot some difference. You should choose one of them as the boldface font and don't rely on both.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I adapted your preamble to the font I have but the problem persists. So maybe I’ll use Linux Libertine O instead of Linux Libertine G if the problem comes from the font.

Comment: @Bastien I'd go for Libertinus, which is maintained and developed.

Comment: @Bastien I added the setup for Libertinus and also a final comment.